# jQuery text() with replace() doesn't replace the text

Tags: jquery, html, text, replace

I have the following H2:

```
<h2 id="resetPWSuccess">Password reset instructions have been sent to *|RESETPASSWORDEMAIL|*</h2>
```

I want to replace the `*|RESETPASSWORDEMAIL|*` with current email address that I have in the jQuery variable `emailAddress`.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$('h2#resetPWSuccess').text().replace('*|RESETPASSWORDEMAIL|*', emailAddress).show();
```

Is there a way to update the h2 text - I prefer one line if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this instead :

```
$('#resetPWSuccess').text(
   $('#resetPWSuccess').text().replace('*|RESETPASSWORDEMAIL|*', emailAddress)
).show();
```

---

Note that I also removed the `h2` from your selector : it's useless and slower than just using the id. When you ask jQuery to search for `#resetPWSuccess`, it uses the very fast native `getElementById` function.

From jQuery's source code :

```
// Shortcuts
if ( (match = rquickExpr.exec( selector )) ) {
    // Speed-up: Sizzle("#ID")
    if ( (m = match[1]) ) {
        if ( nodeType === 9 ) {
            elem = context.getElementById( m );
```

Comment: worked great and will accept - just time limit pending. Can I ask about dropping the h2 (for my education). How come this is faster? Does it alter the jquery search of the DOM somehow?

Comment: appreciate more then I can say - never would have know that... many updates now to do :)... thankyou

Comment: You have the same property with class based selector. If `'.theclass'` matches your need, don't add anything to the selector.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest a different approach:

```
<h2 id="resetPWSuccess">Password reset instructions have been sent to <span id="resetPWemail"></span></h2>
```

And the corresponding js:

```
$('#resetPWemail').text(emailAddress);
$('#resetPWSuccess').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like that.

```
$('#resetPWSuccess').text(
  $('#resetPWSuccess').text().replace('*|RESETPASSWORDEMAIL|*', 'neeraj@gmail.com')
)
```

See Demo [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PgzrU/54/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#resetPWSuccess").text(
  $('#resetPWSuccess').text().
     replace('*|RESETPASSWORDEMAIL|*', $("#EmailID").val()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even simply do this

```
 <h2 id='resetPWSuccess'></h2>

 $('h2#resetPWSuccess').text('Password reset instructions have been sent to '+emailaddress).show();
```