# Remove “ ” from a string - jQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm currently developing my website for mobile version in wordpress and customizing it with HTML/CSS & jQuery/JS.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is, that I would like to remove  -> “ ” from a string. **Currently it looks as it shows on the image bellow:**

[image]

**The orignal HTML code of the category result:**

```
<div class="nm-shop-results-bar  is-category">
   <ul>
      <li class="nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset">
         <a id="nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset" data-shop-url="http://localhost/wordpress/shop/"> 
            <span>“Avtoreparatura”</span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

With the code bellow, I've removed "Showing" next to the category:

```
        jQuery('.nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset a:contains("Showing")').each(function(){
          jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().split("Showing").join(""));
            jQuery("#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset").removeAttr("href"); });
               jQuery('#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset').click(function() {
                    {return false;}
                });
```

I have tried to remove the -> “ ” with this code; it does the work in console, but I can't execute it properly.

```
jQuery('#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset span').text().replace('“','').replace('”','');
```

Had anyone dealt with this before? Please help your man out :)

**UPDATE**
The question, has already been answered on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039262/jquery-text-with-replace-doesnt-replace-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

You should put it somewhere, so you should do this way:

```js
jQuery('#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset span').text(
  jQuery('#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset span').text().replace('“','').replace('”','')
);
```

You're just changing it but not using it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset span').text().replace('“','').replace('”','');`

Will do the job, but it returns a new string which you then must capture and set as the new text value:

```
const el = jQuery('#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset span');
el.text(el.text().replace('“','').replace('”',''));
```